# How can I create service return values of longitude and latitude from json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-routing, angular-resource

**How to create service return values of  longitude and latitude from JSON?**

I have the following URL:

```
http://192.168.7.xxx:9200/location/_doc/27737
```

This URL JSON below:

```
    {"_index":"location","_type":"_doc","_id":"27737","_version":1,"_seq_no":5577,"_primary_term":1,"found":true,"_source":{"Locid":27737,"GPS1":"25.0173, 121.462","GPS2":"25°01'02.2\"N 121°27'44.8\"E","CompanyID":1005070,"ads":"142 Sec. 1, HsIn Nan Rd cung Ko Dšst, New Taipei City, Taiwan","Crid":75,"con":"Taiwan","Ctid":5894,"Cn":"Zhonghe District","pushdate":"2019-12-26T03:38:20.883"}}
```

I need to create service return two values from GPS1:

```
longitude: 25.0173,
latitude: 121.462
```

Based on Location `Id` parameter `27737`.

So that I need to create service take location id parameters and return two values of GPS1 25.0173 and 25.0173

```
getDataService(locationid): Observable<any> {    
     const url = "http://192.168.7.xxx:9200/location/_doc/27737";    
       return this.httpClient.get(`${url} + locationid`);    
   }
```

on `ngOinInit` Event

```
ngOnInit  
{  
call service here  
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking how to parse json?

Comment: thank you i ask how to create service get values of longtude and latitude from json

Comment: I actually need to get values of "25.0173, 121.462" of GPS1 from json above so that i need to create service do that and calling on ngonint

Comment: are my question until not clear if not clear tell me i will give more details

Comment: this url exist on thread above return json i need to get two values from json returned this is actually what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the json returned in a variable called response. You could simply do

```
getDataService(locationid): Observable<any> {    
     const url = "http://192.168.7.xxx:9200/location/_doc/27737";    
       return this.httpClient.get(`${url} + locationid`)
          .then(response => {
             const [latitude, longitude] = response._source.GPS1.trim().split(",");
             return {latitude, longitude};
           });
   }
```

Comment: thank you for reply this is actually result what i need but can you help me to write full code for service and how to call on ngonit

Comment: I have edited my answer. I am not very good at angular but assuming httpClient returns a promise so you could do a then to get the response and perform necessary modifications.

Comment: thank you for reply How to call service above on ngOninit event component

Comment: suppose I have component have two variables lat : number ,lng : number How to recieve values from service

Comment: this is good but location exist on nginit represent model or what

Comment: split (,) return two values if i need to return two values separately what i do meaning i need to get latitude= ,longtude=

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return an observable containing the latitude and longitude for the given locationId. The locationId needs to be passed in the url as shown below.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

```
getDataService(locationId): Observable<any> {    
     const url = 'http://192.168.7.xxx:9200/location/_doc/' + locationId;    
     return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
       map(response => {
         const [longitude, latitude] = response._source.GPS1.split(",");
         return {latitude: latitude.trim(), longitude: longitude.trim()};
       })
     );
}
```

Then call the service in ngOnInit and get the location's latitude and longitude.

```
latitude: number;
longitude: number;
constructor(private service: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const locationId = '27737';
  this.service.getDataService(locationId).subscribe((location) => {
    this.latitude = Number(location.latitude);
    this.longitude = Number(location.longitude);
  })
}
```

Comment: split (,) return two values if i need to return two values separately what i do meaning i need to get latitude= ,longtude=

Comment: split(',') splits the string into an array on ','. In javascript, the array can be used to initialize 2 new values. In the code above, I have split the string on ',' and then saved the values in 2 separate variables longitude and latitude. I have than returned the longitude and latitude as a new object.
Please clarify what exactly do you need.

Comment: and location defined on component is represent model are this correct or not

Comment: subscribe((location) location is model are this correct

Comment: I have edited the answer. 2 properties latitude and longitude of the component can be set in the subscribe method from the returned location object. location is just a variable name, it does not represent any model. It contains 2 properties, latitude and longitude.